# How to give image Animations to multiple images at Different Locations in a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, nstimer

> How to give 'image' Animations to `multiple images` at `Different
>   Locations` in a 'UIView'?

1) I had 3 images.

2) i want to Add these `3 Images` at `3 different locations` animatedly, means add one by one images `animatedly` with `some duration`??

***How can I achieve this?***

Comment: you need uiimageview animation fast to slow for Perticular area?

Comment: UIView animateWithDuration?

Comment: @Shreyank....Not Fast to slow...but we want to add 3 images one by one after some duration at 3 different locations...one image at one place, after placed that image, next image animate and come into next place like that

Comment: @SimonMoshenko.....add 3 different images to 3 different locations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement you want to animate image one by one

for that purpose use completion block of first image animation to animate second image and so on like below code

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-t%d",1]]];
[imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-t%d",2]]];
[imgView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIImageView *imgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-t%d",2]]];
[imgView3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view addSubview:imgView2];
[self.view addSubview:imgView3];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
        [imgView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 150, 0, 150, 150)];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
            [imgView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 150, 150, 150)];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        }];

    }];

}];
```

It will Help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 3 views are `_redView`, `_greenView` and `_blueView` check out following method to move those from one to another location. I have used random location you can give specific if you want. [Here you can have working example of it](https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace) just select `ViewAnimationsTest` project of the work space and run.

```
- (int) randomFloatingGenerator : (int) max{
    return arc4random() % max;
}

- (void) animate3Views {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         _redView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator : 270], [self randomFloatingGenerator:480]);
                         _greenView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator : 270], [self randomFloatingGenerator:480]);
                         _blueView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator : 270], [self randomFloatingGenerator:480]);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self animate3Views];//if don;t want continuous translation remove this line
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Here you can have working example of it, https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace just select ViewAnimationsTest project of the work space and run.

Comment: @rptwsthi...in that examples, could u tell me which one i have to use

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use 3 animations called with delay.

```
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIView *view = myViews[i];
        CGRect frame = [self frameForViewAtIndex: i];
        NSTimeInterval duration = 0.5;
        NSTimeInterval delay = i * 0.5;

        [UIView animateWithDuration: duration delay: delay options: 0 animations: ^{
            view.frame = frame;
        } completion: nil];
    }
```

Where **myViews** is array of views to be animated, **frameForViewAtIndex:** is the method that returns frame for corresponding view.

Comment: @roselovely Is something  not clear in that piece of code?