# iOS Programmatically Add Left image to UITextField in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitextfield

**

> iOS Programmatically Adding Left image to UITextField in Xcode?

**

1) I want Take a `UIview` with `White Background color`, inside the `View` i added  `4 Textfield's`?

2) I want to add `4 different images` to the `left side` of the `4 different textfields` inside a `View` Having following properties?

**Properties For View**
        i) `corner Radius`---`5`
        ii) `Border Color`----`light Gray Color`

3) How to add `Space` between the `image` and `Placeholder Text` inside the `Textfields` from the below figure and also `add layer` for `all textfields` with `light gray color`?

> How can i Achieve this ????

[The View Combined With `Textfields` and Images like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwEAy.png)

Comment: Use `Autolayout` add `UIImageView` next to `UITextField`

Comment: If this is `UITableViewCell`, just use `cell.imageView.image` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999017/adding-images-to-uitableview

Comment: @Tim007....that textfields i added to the a View only...not Tableview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgforLeft=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgforLeft setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename.png"]];

[imgforLeft setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit 

self. yourTextfield.leftView=imgforLeft;
self. yourTextfield.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

**choice -2**

```
// short answer with out 
self. yourTextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self. yourTextfield.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename.png"]];
```

**Swift**

```
self. yourTextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
self. yourTextfield.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImagename.png"))
```

**Update**

*for TextField1*

```
UIImageView *imgforLeft1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgforLeft1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename1.png"]];

[imgforLeft1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit 

self. yourTextfield1.leftView=imgforLeft1;
self. yourTextfield1.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

  self. yourTextfield1.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(30, 0, 0);
```

*for TextField2*

```
UIImageView *imgforLeft2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgforLeft2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename2.png"]];

[imgforLeft1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit 

self. yourTextfield2.leftView=imgforLeft1;
self. yourTextfield2.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

   self. yourTextfield2.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(30, 0, 0);
```

*for TextField3*

```
UIImageView *imgforLeft3=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgforLeft3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename3.png"]];

[imgforLeft3 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit 

self. yourTextfield3.leftView=imgforLeft1;
self. yourTextfield3.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

  self. yourTextfield3.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(30, 0, 0);
```

*for TextField4*

```
UIImageView *imgforLeft4=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgforLeft4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename4.png"]];

[imgforLeft4 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit 

self. yourTextfield4.leftView=imgforLeft1;
self. yourTextfield4.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

  self. yourTextfield4.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(30, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...I want to add 4 textfileds along with 4 images to the left side of the textfield..sample code please

Comment: @roselovely - hi, 4 images are same or different

Comment: ...different images for different textfields

Comment: @roselovely - answer is only for Objective - C , check the updated answer once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...how to add spacing between image and placeholdertext inside the Textfield

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I hope you do realize that as soon as you started writing the same thing 4 times, you began doing his job instead of hellping...

Comment: @4oby - I agree bro, may be she or he is the fresher , the questioner does not know the conept so sometimes we need to do the help for this.

Comment: @roselovely - add this line `self. yourTextfield1.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(30, 0, 0);` and check the updated answer

Comment: @roselovely - happy to hear , if my answer is useful , give the tick mark for the answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....tick mark not working for me...its showing some warning message like...u want some more reputitions...how to i get reputitions

Answer (score 2):

`UITextfield` have property that allow to set Left View you can use this for your goal

like this

```
[yourTextfield setLeftView:YOURVIEW];
```

Comment: add it one by one lke `[yourTextfield1 setLeftView:YOURVIEW1];`  
 `[yourTextfield2 setLeftView:YOURVIEW2];`  .....

Comment: Refer 

Anbu.Karthik's answer do that way

Comment: answer for this question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540895/how-to-give-image-animations-to-multiple-images-at-different-locations-in-a-uivi

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;


UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 15, 15)];
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
[myTextField addSubView:myImageView];
```

the `CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 15, 15)` part lets you specify the position and size of your image `(xPos, yPos, width, height)`

Comment: @roselovely repeat same thing 4 times... but you might consider using PKT's answer as it's a better way of doing it, I forgot about the default `leftView` and `rightView`